# Log product with exponent becomes equal to summation

Tags: logarithms

I have a question regarding logarithm rules.

Could anyone please explain how does equation (3) derived from equation (2)?

I am especially confused regarding the product of $log$ and $exp()$ changed to summation.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually simpler than you think. These are basic properties of $\log$ right
$$
\log xy=\log x+\log y\\
\log\frac xy = \log x-\log y
$$
Then we also know $\log$ is the inverse function of $\exp$, then we have
$$
\log \frac{\exp X}{Z} = \log \exp X-\log Z = -\log Z + X
$$

Substitute $Z :=Z(X^n,w) $ $X:=\langle w,\psi(X^n,Y^n)\rangle$ you get what you want.